# What feature can be used to guard against phantom read anomaly instead of the Serializable isolation level?

Tags: sql, database, serializable, isolation-level

We know the **Serializable isolation level** guards against the Phantom reads anomaly, Instead of that what feature can be used to guard against Phantom reads anomaly?

In one of my assignments, I'm trying to do asking these questions.

```
1. Which isolation level guards against such an anomaly?   
2. What feature can be used to guard against this anomaly?
```

So I need to know the answer for Question 2

Comment: That **IS** the feature to use to avoid this anomaly - there aren't dozens of features to handle this - one is there and that's the one to use

Comment: In one of my assignments, I'm trying to do asking these questions.
1. Which isolation level guards against such an anomaly?   
2. What feature can be used to guard against this anomaly? 
So I need to know the answer for Question 2.

Comment: @marc_s thank you for the response. But my assignment asks to mention another feature rather than the Serializable isolation level.